# Facebook Ad Pixel Conversion tracking for Messenger Bot

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, messenger

I'm creating a Facebook Messenger Bot thats powered by a python backend.

I'm promoting my bot via FB ads and am trying to figure out if theres any possible way to use Pixel's Conversion tracking to improve metrics (pretty sure facebook's ad placement trys to optimize based on conversion results)

Anyone know if this is possible? Everything I'm finding so far is javascript code that you need to put on your website, and I don't have or need a website for my bot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured it out.. User clicks ad -> opens up a website to get the pixel conversion hit -> immediate re-direct back to messenger.

Answer (score 0):

"User clicks ad 
-> opens up a website to get the pixel conversion hit 
-> immediate re-direct back to messenger"

I don't see how this is helping, as the pixel conversion hit happens before any action happens within the chat.

If you want to track a certain action within the chat, couldn't you redirect to a website and re-direct back to the chat from within the chat, say in the middle of the question flow?

Comment: Eh.. for what I'm doing I don't want users to leave the messenger bot. Once they are in they should only interact with the bot. I only need the pixel conversion so my ads are able to place correctly (looks like facebook places ads better if they create a conversion)